# explode and then foreach data not the same (php error?)

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have 2 string :

```
$data1 = "8,11,";
$data2 = "2,3,";
```

and I do this :

```
$stuff = explode(",", $data1, -1);
$amount = explode(",", $data2, -1);
```

So the array like this :

```
$stuff have an Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 11 ) 
$amount have an Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )
```

and then do foreach like this :

```
foreach($stuff as $index => $value){

    $query= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
    $STH2 = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH2->execute(array($value['0']));

    while($Products_all = $STH2->fetch()){
and so on....
.......
```

What I want to do is to print product id 8 and id 11. In fact, it get product id 8 and id 1. What's wrong with my code? Why it has product id 1 not 11?
Thank you.

additional question: why it has to change to "$value" ?

Comment: change $value['0'] to $value

Comment: $STH2->execute(array($value['0'])); should be $STH2->execute(array($value));. When you use $value['0'] you only get the 1st char of your $value

Comment: Where is your debug statement?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 $STH2->execute(array($value['0']));
```

to

```
 $STH2->execute(array($value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You put into SQL query only first char of value (`$value[0]`) instead of full value.

```
$STH2->execute(array($value));
```

The second thing is, why you use queries in FOR loop insterad of one query?

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE id IN (8, 11)
```

Comment: Because I want to use both of the array (stuff and amount), using 'foreach'.

Comment: OK, no problem. With 3 queries there is no problem, with hundreds it will be worse and slower. The solution is in my answer, remove [0]

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, sry change this line:

```
$STH2->execute(array($value['0']));
```

to

```
$STH2->execute(array($value));
```